# How to perform docker-compose healthcheck for pgadmin4

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have created yml file for postgresql and pgadmin4. Want to do healthcheck on these two containers. How can i do this?

Answer (score 4):

For PostgreSQL you want to run from the container `pg_isready -U username`, where `username` is a valid username for the DB.

For pgAdmin you want to run from the container `wget -O - http://localhost:80/misc/ping`.

This would look something like that:

```yaml
services:
  postgre:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=foo
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "foo"]
    ...

  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "wget", "-O", "-", "http://localhost:80/misc/ping"]
    ...
```

You can find a real world example of this [here](https://gitlab.com/openetymologymap/open-etymology-map/-/blob/a9635efc83e36d5913b9889545607a66e58a7de2/docker-compose.yml#L88)

Answer (score 3):

For Postgres container health check variable, use the following:

```yaml
healthcheck:
  test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready --quiet --dbname=$${POSTGRES_DB}--username=$${POSTGRES_USER} || exit 1"]
  interval: 10s
  timeout: 10s
  start_period: 30s
  retries: 3
```

For PgAdmin container health check variable, use the following:

```yaml
 healthcheck:
   test: ["CMD", "wget", "-O", "-", "http://localhost:80/misc/ping"]
   interval: 10s
   timeout: 10s
   start_period: 160s
   retries: 3
```

**Note**:
For pgAdmin container, the 'start_period' variable should be at least 140s otherwise will face the following error/warning:

> worker pid [<>] has terminated due signal 9

Answer (score 0):

from [postgresql documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pg-isready.html) **pg_isready** only checks the connection status of a PostgreSQL database server.

this is healthcheck if use:

```yaml
healthcheck:
  test: ["CMD-SHELL", "PGPASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD} psql -U ${DATABASE_USER} -d ${DATABASE_NAME} -c 'SELECT 1;' || exit 1"]
```